# How to find all the functions that has been *used* in a python script?

Tags: python

Say I have a python script in this form

```py
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6]
x.sort()
print(np.sum(x))
```

I want to extract all the functions that have been used in this script. For this example the outcome should be `list.sort, np.sum, print`. I can list all the builtin functions and then expand that list with `dir(numpy)`. And then check whether each of those functions appear in the code.

But what if there is a function like `np.linalg.norm(x)`? How will I find this function since `norm` will not be returned by `dir(numpy)`.

Note: I understand many other functions can be invoked which does not appear in the code. For this example `list.__init__`. But I only want those functions that appears in the code. Simply put, I want all the words/tokens that will be colored yellow by vscode in Dark+ theme. Is there any possible way to use `rope` for this problem?

Comment: Why do you need them? Maybe you're facing with the XY problem!

Comment: I am trying to build a code competition game where I need to know the functions used by an user in real time.

Comment: By used do you mean called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to do something like that:

```py
import ast


code = """
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6]
x.sort()
print(np.sum(x))
"""

module = ast.parse(code)

for node in ast.walk(module):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
        try:
            parent_name = node.func.value.id + '.'
        except AttributeError:
            parent_name = ''
        if isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
            print(f'{parent_name}{node.func.id}')
        else:
            print(f'{parent_name}{node.func.attr}')

# output:
#  x.sort
#  print
#  np.sum
```

Of course, there is `x.sort` instead of `list.sort` but I didn't find out how to get the actual parent type of the method.